# Can't access write permissions on NTFS partition after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, permissions

I am dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 10. I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 a few days ago. everything works fine, but I have no write permission to the NTFS partitions. I can access them but cant write to them.

I have tried running `sudo chmod 777 -R files`, but got told that I only have Read permissions.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mounted your partition **read-only**, and you must remount it with **read/write** permissions.

This is typically done by this command:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/(ntfs partition file name)
```